# Jumping to an excel cell after reading a barcode to see if there is a match

Tags: excel, vba, barcode-scanner

I have an excel sheet with barcodes and details of products. I would like to use a barcode scanner to find items associated with those barcodes in my excel sheet (for inventory purposes) and mark them. I would like excel to jump into the corresponding cell. I have tried creating a macro by reading similar posts and this is as far as I have got:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim code As Variant
 Dim matchedCell As Range


    code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")
    Set matchedCell = Range("C2:C100").Find(what:=code, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not matchedCell Is Nothing Then
    Range(matchedCell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Else: MsgBox "Barcode Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

This only highlights the cell. Ideally, I would like to highlight the whole row. I would also like to jump to the corresponding cell. I have no experience in this and I just pulled a couple of different examples that I found online until I got this to work without error message. How can I modify this to add additional functions?

I also have a problem with entering the barcode into the inputbox. All I can do is get it entered into a cell by scanning it or manually enter the number into the input box - how could I make it enter the scanned code into this inputbox? The cursor is in the right place, but that is ignored.

Thank you

Comment: 1. `Range(matchedCell.Address)` - no need to use the `Address`, just use `matchedCell` directly, since it is a `Range`. 2. To highlight the whole row, `matchedCell.EntireRow.Interior...`. 3. `matchedCell.Activate` to jump to the corresponding cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim code As Variant Dim matchedCell As Range

    code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")

    Set matchedCell = Range("C2:C100").Find(what:=code, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                      lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

    If Not matchedCell Is Nothing Then
        With matchedCell
            Application.Goto .Cells(1)
            .Resize(1, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Barcode Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did I miss something - where are you getting the 10 from?

Comment: I use that in place of `EntireRow` because I don't like to highlight beyond the data: OP is free to adjust to suit...