# Un-highlighting cells when next barcode is scanned

Tags: excel, vba, highlight, barcode-scanner

I've been searching for a way to add a barcode lookup system to some inventory sheets on excel. Looking on this forum I found just about the exact solution I was looking for. I've been trying to figure out how to add a feature but have gotten nowhere with it (very little coding experience). The sheet jumps to the corresponding cell and gets highlighted, which is needed since it doesn't bring the cell to the top of the sheet view, the code just seems to make sure that the desired cell is displayed anywhere on the sheet as long as it's there. So the highlight is helpful in finding the right cell on the page quickly, but when I go to scan and find another barcode all the previous scanned cells remain highlighted. So far I just un-highlight them manually from the home tab, but I'm wondering if there is something that can be added to the code to Un-highlight the cells when I scan the next barcode?
Also, I'm using the excel template for inventory that highlights the cell rows if the item needs to be reordered. Not sure how much of a problem this adds.

Thanks in advance if anyone has any ideas.

Here is the code that I found on the forum, it's the same except I just changed the color value (a sea of bright yellow was too much to look at after a hundred rows):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim code As Variant
Dim matchedCell As Range

code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")

Set matchedCell = Range("C2:C100").Find(what:=code, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                  lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

If Not matchedCell Is Nothing Then
    With matchedCell
        Application.Goto .Cells(1)
        .Resize(1, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Barcode Not Found"
End If

End Sub
```

(original forum source for the code above: [Jumping to an excel cell after reading a barcode to see if there is a match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642555/jumping-to-an-excel-cell-after-reading-a-barcode-to-see-if-there-is-a-match?answertab=active#tab-top) )

[Before Picture of highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiTr2.jpg)

[After picture of highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJv8D.jpg)

Comment: "Also, I'm using the excel template for inventory that highlights the cell rows if the item needs to be reordered." So it is possible that you change color for a product to e.g red if it needs to be reordered, after that someone search this product (automatically it changes to blue), later someone looks for another product and you want to restore red color? Is it really to be such a complicated thing? What when a product needs to be reordered and its higlighted (blue) because somoene was searching for it? How do you recognize that? Give us a sample to better understand, it makes no sense to me

Comment: The template from excel changes color when the item needs to be reordered, it also has a little red flag it puts in another cell. With the flag, I don't care about highlighting for reorder. I only added that part to the question because I didn't know if it might cause any problems with the code above or any changes that should be done to it, and just wanted to give all info. My only goal is to have the cell un-highlight after I'm done with it, the blue highlight is only to pinpoint the cell it is trying to jump to. After a few scans when many cells are blue it becomes a pointless feature.

Comment: I added pictures. The highlight it does when it wants to reorder I don't care about (I'll probably turn it off anyways later on), the flag symbol is more than enough for me. It's just that the blue highlight after the scan is useless after so many cells are highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly it's really easy to solve your problem: just simply restore color before your main code.

For example:

1. Click on your sheet to activate it
2. Run this code to check color code:

   ```
     Sub getColor()

         MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Interior.color 

     End Sub
   ```
3. Write down your color number
4. Modify your macro code

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory List")

    Dim rangeToLook As Range
    Set rangeToLook = ws.Range("C2:C100")

    Dim wholeRange As Range
    Set wholeRange = rangeToLook.Resize(, 10)

    ' change 14408667 to yours grey color code here
    wholeRange.Cells.Interior.color = 14408667

    Dim code As Variant    
        code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")

    Dim matchedCell As Range
    Set matchedCell = rangeToLook.Find(what:=code, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                      lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

        If Not matchedCell Is Nothing Then
            With matchedCell
                Application.Goto .Cells(1)
                .Resize(1, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "Barcode Not Found"
        End If

    End Sub
   ```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. And great job with the color code, when I ran the check it came out to the same number that you had. Thank you.
Dziękuję Ci za wszystko:)